# What is the easiest way to create publication-quality plots under Linux?

Tags: data-visualization

We may assume that we have CSV file and we want a very basic line plot with several lines on one plot and a simple legend.

Comment: How do you define 'publication-quality'? Please elaborate on what aspects you like to see covered... e.g. color use, line widths, etc. Should answers focus on font size, instead?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The easiest way is to use R

Use `read.csv` to enter the data into R, then use a combination of the `plot` and `line` commands

If you want something really special, then look at the libraries [ggplot2](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/) or [lattice](http://lmdvr.r-forge.r-project.org/figures/figures.html).

In `ggplot2` the following commands should get you started.

```
require(ggplot2)
#You would use read.csv here
N = 10
d = data.frame(x=1:N,y1=runif(N),y2=rnorm(N), y3 = rnorm(N, 0.5))
p = ggplot(d)

p = p+geom_line(aes(x, y1, colour="Type 1"))
p = p+geom_line(aes(x, y2, colour="Type 2"))
p = p+geom_line(aes(x, y3, colour="Type 3"))
#Add points
p = p+geom_point(aes(x, y3, colour="Type 3"))
print(p)
```

This would give you the following plot:

[image: Line-plot]

**Saving plots in R**

Saving plots in R is straightforward:

```
#Look at ?jpeg to other different saving options
jpeg("figure.jpg")
print(p)#for ggplot2 graphics
dev.off()
```

Instead of `jpeg`'s you can also save as a `pdf` or postscript file:

```
#This example uses R base graphics
#Just change to print(p) for ggplot2
pdf("figure.pdf")
plot(d$x,y1, type="l")
lines(d$x, y2)
dev.off()
```

Comment: How about saving to file?

Comment: Or a little more succinctly with melt and qplot: `m <- melt(d, id = "x"); qplot(variable, value, data = m, colour = variable)`

Comment: Actually, an even easier way is to use R+deducer with ggplot2 (there is a new release of this which is about to come out in the next few months.  A beta is currently available)

Comment: Nice example, but the plot is hardly publication quality. Or at least none of the journals I publish in would accept it.

Comment: "Hardly publication quality"???? I realise that it isn't perfect - the phrase "...should you get you started.." covers that bit. But with a little additional work, i.e. axis labels, I would say it's fine. BTW, what journals do you publish in?

Comment: For my part graphs that are black and white plots without shaded backgrounds that use different icons or line types are important.  Also an easy way to do confidence intervals (where appropriate) would be nice too.

Answer (score 13):

It's hard to go past R for graphics. You could do what you want in 3 lines. For example, assuming the csv file has four columns:

```
x <- read.csv("file.csv")
matplot(x[,1],x[,2:4],type="l",col=1:3)
legend("topleft",legend=c("A","B","C"),lty=1,col=1:3)
```

Comment: R produces some of the best quality graphics around. As an editor of an international research journal, I would love all our authors to use R.

Comment: .. see my comment on the question... how do you define 'publication-quality', or 'best quality'... from a editor perspective?

Comment: I like to see vector graphics (no jpegs), graphical design following the principles of Tufte & Cleveland, readable fonts, uncluttered legends, no shaded backgrounds, sensible axis limits and tick intervals, labelled axes, no overlap of text and plotting characters or lines, etc. Most authors use the default settings of their software, so good software has good defaults. This is where Excel fails miserably and R does pretty well. But it is possible to produce lousy graphs in R and good graphs in Excel. It's just easier to produce high quality graphics in R.

Answer (score 12):

R is definitely the answer.  I would just add to what Rob and Colin already said:

To improve the quality of your plots, you should consider using [the **Cairo** package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Cairo/index.html) for the output device.  That will greatly improve the *quality* of the final graphics.  You simply call the function before plotting and it redirects to Cairo as the output device.

```
Cairo(600, 600, file="plot.png", type="png", bg="white")
plot(rnorm(4000),rnorm(4000),col="#ff000018",pch=19,cex=2) # semi-transparent red
dev.off() # creates a file "plot.png" with the above plot
```

Lastly, in terms of putting it in a publication, that's the role that `Sweave` plays.  It makes combining plots with your paper a trivial operation (and has the added benefit of leaving you with something that is *reproducible* and understandable).  Use `cacheSweave` if you have long-running computations.

Comment: Probably better than using Cairo to produce a bitmap image is to save graphs as vectors, which are resolution independent, so look better when resized, and always suit print resolution - I like svg, which can easily be edited with [inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org).

Answer (score 11):

My favorite tool is Python with [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/).

The advantages:

- Immediate export from the environment where I do my experiments in
- Support for the scipy/numpy data structures
- Familiar syntax/options (matlab background)
- Full latex support for labels/legends etc. So same typesetting as in the rest of your document!

Specifically, for different file formats like svg and eps, use the `format` parameter of [`savefig`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html).

An example:
input.csv

```
"Line 1",0.5,0.8,1.0,0.9,0.9
"Line 2",0.2,0.7,1.2,1.1,1.1
```

Code:

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

legends = []
for row in csv.reader(open('input.csv')):
    legends.append(row[0])
    plt.plot(row[1:])

plt.legend(legends)
plt.savefig("out.svg", format='svg')
```

Comment: Could you put a code snippet for completness? It would be very useful for people in the future finding this page.

Comment: @Łukasz Hmm, some suggestion how to upload an svg figure?

Comment: You could have mentioned in your answer that matplotlib allows rendering of all typography in the plot with LaTeX so it perfectly integrates visually.

Comment: I wonder why matplotlib hasn't been integrated into R yet?

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the sample galleries for three popular visualization libraries:

- [matplotlib gallery](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/gallery.html) (Python)
- [R graph gallery](http://addictedtor.free.fr/graphiques/) (R) -- (also see [ggplot2](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/), scroll down to reference)
- [prefuse visualization gallery](http://prefuse.org/gallery/) (Java)

For the first two, you can even view the associated source code -- the simple stuff is simple, not many lines of code.  The prefuse case will have the requisite Java boilerplate code.  All three support a number of backends/devices/renderers (pdf, ps, png, etc).  All three are clearly capable of high quality graphics.

I think it pretty much boils down to which language are you most comfortable working in.  Go with that.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is [Gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/)

Answer (score 1):

Easy is relative. No tool is easy until you know how to use it. Some tools may appear more difficult at first, but provide you with much more fine-grained control once you master them.

I have recently started to make my plots in [pgfplots](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/). Being a LaTeX package (on top of `tikz`), it is particularly good at making things look good. Fonts will be consistent with the rest of the document and it's much easier to integrate your plots visually. It's not the easiest option to make plots, but it's a rather easy way to make plots that are certainly publication-quality.