# Good online resource with tips on graphing association between two numeric variables under various conditions

Tags: data-visualization, correlation, teaching, rule-of-thumb, scatterplot

#### Context:

Over the while I've acquired a set of heuristics on how to effectively plot the association between two numeric variables. I imagine most people who work with data would have a similar set of rules.

Examples of such rules might be:

- If one of the variables is positively skewed, consider plotting that axis on a log scale.
- If there are a lot of data points (e.g., n > 1000), adopt a different strategy such as using some form of partial transparency, or sampling the data;
- If one of the variables takes on a limited number of discrete categories, consider using a jitter or a sunflower plot;
- If there are three or more variables, consider using a scatterplot matrix;
- Fitting some form of trend line is often useful;
- Adjust the size of the plotting character to the sample size (for bigger n, use a smaller plotting character);
- and so on.

#### Question:

I'd like to be able to refer students to a web page or site that explains these and other tricks for effectively plotting associations between two numeric variables, perhaps with examples.

- Are there any pages or sites on the internet that do a good job of this?

Comment: If you can find it, the printed "Graphics" manual that came with older copies of Systat (pre-Windows, believe it or not) would be an excellent resource.  Not only did it illustrate all these rules (as I recall), it was full of pithy and excellent advice.

Comment: @whuber, a great comment. Leland Wilkinson, the primary author of Systat, and also the author of [The Grammar of Graphics](http://www.amazon.com/Grammar-Graphics-Statistics-Computing/dp/0387245448) (which is more of a computer science book than a statistics book), has a very fine taste for graphical display of data. His presentations are always very effective in delivering their messages.

Comment: @Jeromy, you may already know the *ggplot2* package for R, but now that The Grammar of Graphics was mentioned, I thought to mention it too. I find the package, the book and the online [reference manual](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/) by Hadley Wickham very useful for turning numeric variables into useful plots and graphics.

Comment: @Jeromy why not rephrase the question (separately) as a community wiki, requesting one post per rule? That way, rather than a set of links, we could have a votable set of rules and create the resource here.

Comment: @David Okay, I've added a general community wiki question on best resources for designing plots http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16631/what-is-a-good-resource-for-designing-and-producing-graphical-representations-of

Comment: @Jeromy perhaps you misunderstood. I meant a question for which each answer would be a rule / technique rather than a resource. That way, the question would be the resource rather than a collection of links

Comment: @David okay. I see what you mean now. I've edited the question a bit: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16631/what-is-a-good-resource-for-designing-and-producing-graphical-representations-of; There is this question at the moment http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/396/what-best-practices-should-i-follow-when-preparing-plots ; I'll leave it to you to ask a question if you want.

Answer (score 14):

I can't think of great online resources off the top of my head, but a nice (and easily downloadable) book chapter that narrates how to visually explore a large, multidimensional data set in a thoughtful way is [Brendan O'Connor and Lukas Biewald's chapter](http://assets.doloreslabs.com/blog/oconnor_biewald_beautiful_data_final_nonlayout_20090803_20090327.pdf) (warning: link is directly to a PDF) from [*Beautiful Data*](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596157128.do). The chapter is particularly useful as a teaching resource because it incorporates R code into the narrative.

Also, upon further reflection, I think John Tukey's classic ["Some Graphic and Semigraphic Displays"](http://www.edwardtufte.com/tufte/tukey) (conveniently posted on Edward Tufte's website) is a really wonderful, albeit somewhat idiosyncratic, introduction to visualization.

For some reason, I seem to be thinking of book chapters...

Comment: +1 At least these chapters are available on the Web: I think that qualifies.  Thanks, Aaron.

Comment: @ whuber thanks for posting the bounty; and @ashaw both links make for interesting reading.

Comment: I notice that the Tukey article is a predecessor of the expanded treatment found in his book *EDA* (1977) (excepting the final section on hanging rootograms and histograms).

Answer (score 11):

#### Recent references:

- [Kelleher and Wagner 2011 "Ten guidelines for effective data visualization in scientific publications"](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.envsoft.2010.12.006) provides a nice set of rules. The rules, with references (but not the full article) are available without subscription, although university students would likely have full access.
- [United Nations 2009 "Making Data Meaningful"](http://unstats.un.org/unsd/EconStatKB/Attachment187.aspx) provides a nice overview, with rules and examples, including a section on 'emerging technologies'.

#### Older, but relevant resources

- SIGGGRAPH provides some excellent tutorials, though lacking examples, including:

  - [Senay and Ignatius 1999 "Rules and Principles of Scientific Data Visualization"](http://www.siggraph.org/education/materials/HyperVis/percept/visrules.htm)
  - [Domik 1999 "Tutorial on Visualization"](http://www.siggraph.org/education/materials/HyperVis/domik/folien.html)
- A good summary of Tufte can be found here:

  - [Globus 1994 "Principles of Information Display for Visualization Practitioners"](http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~rbm/cs100/notes/spreadsheets/tufte_paper.html)

Comment: +1 The rules and tutorials look useful, comprehensive--and forbidding!  How is it possible to write about graphics without providing *a single illustration*? :-)

Comment: The choice was difficult, but I have awarded the bounty to this reply because overall it best addresses the question as asked.  The UN document appears to be especially useful and accessible to students, with its plain language and many clear examples.